# TinyMCE and Vuejs as a component

Tags: javascript, tinymce, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to make a Vue Component for TinyMCE but I am facing some problems that I can not solve! Can anybody help me? **Or maybe advise a better way to walk**?

**There is my Component**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import _ from 'lodash'

export
default {

  props: {
    model: {
      default () {
        return null
      }
    },
    showLeadInfo: {
      default () {
        return false
      }
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      id: 'editor_' + _.random(10000, 99999)
    }
  },

  watch: {
    model() {
      if (this.model == null)
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
    }
  },

  ready() {
    var vm = this;
    tinyMCE.baseURL = "/vendor/tinymce/";
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "#" + vm.id,
      theme: "modern",
      height: 200,
      plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
      ],
      toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
      style_formats: [{
        title: 'Bold text',
        inline: 'b'
      }, {
        title: 'Red text',
        inline: 'span',
        styles: {
          color: '#ff0000'
        }
      }, {
        title: 'Red header',
        block: 'h1',
        styles: {
          color: '#ff0000'
        }
      }, {
        title: 'Example 1',
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'example1'
      }, {
        title: 'Example 2',
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'example2'
      }, {
        title: 'Table styles'
      }, {
        title: 'Table row 1',
        selector: 'tr',
        classes: 'tablerow1'
      }],
      setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
          vm.model = editor.getContent();
        });
      }
    });

  },

  events: {
    updateTinyValue(value) {
      tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(value);
    }
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea :id="id" v-model="model" v-el:editor></textarea>
```

**PS:** It is made up with Vueify so there is a template and a script tag wrapping that code.

My biggest problem is when I try to instantiate multiple editors I cant clear the right component because of this code `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(value)`... I've have tried `tinyMCE.get('#' + this.id).setContent()` but it does not work!

Somebody have any clue?

Other thing is about ja TinyMCE Plugins... I am using Bower + Gulp to manage my assets! I would like to put all the plugins on my gulpfile (I am using Laravel 5)... Right now the TinyMCE plugins are been loaded one by one and it takes a lot of time!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `activeEditor` you can use `getInstanceById`:

```
tinyMCE.getInstanceById(this.id).setContent(value);
```

Looking at the docs that might be the old version of tinyMCE, might also try:

```
tinymce.editors[this.id].setContent(value);
```

Also check out this answer, which uses a Vue directive to manage this automatically: [VueJS and tinyMCE, custom directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532847/vuejs-and-tinymce-custom-directives) .  This allows you to make a tinyMCE editor simply with `<textarea v-editor :body="body"></textarea>`.  You'll need to adapt it a but but directives are the way to go on this.

Another example directive: https://jsfiddle.net/edwindeveloper90/edjc82z0/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**vue-easy-tinymce**](https://github.com/m3esma/vue-easy-tinymce) as a component, this is a simple and powerful package for easy usage of **tinymce** in **Vue.js** project.

---

Or simply:

```
var yourComponent = {

    props: {
        id: {type: String, default: 'editor'},
        value: {default: ''}
    },

    data: function () {
        return {
            objTinymce: null
        }
    },

    template: '<textarea :id="id" :value="value"></textarea>',

    mounted: function () {

        var component = this;
        var initialOptions = {
            target: this.$el,
            init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
                editor.on('Change KeyUp Undo Redo', function (e) {
                    component.value = editor.getContent();
                });
                component.objTinymce = editor;
            }
        };
        tinymce.init(initialOptions);
    },

    watch: {
        value: function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var component = this;
            if (component.value !== this.objTinymce.getContent())
                this.objTinymce.setContent(component.value);
            else
                component.$emit('input', newValue);
        }
    }

};
```